# How to break large cell into multiple lines and adjust table?

Tags: python, psycopg2, restructuredtext

I'm using [pytablewriter](https://github.com/thombashi/pytablewriter) to write data from postgres to a rst grid table. My code is:

```py
from pytablewriter import RstGridTableWriter as RST
import psycopg2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with connection.cursor(name='foo') as cursor:
        cursor.itersize = 100000
        cursor.execute(query)

        for raw_row in cursor:
            row = [
                raw_row[0],
                raw_row[1],
                raw_row[2],
                ', '.join([item for item in raw_row[3] if item])
            ]

            matrix.append(row)

    writer = RST(
        table_name='DocTable',
        headers=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'],
        value_matrix=matrix
    )

    writer.dump('./sample.rst')
```

The last value of each row fetched is a list of strings. For every iteration, the code above turns the list of strings into a comma separated string. That string can be potentially large and result in a large column.

I'd like to know how to output a table with fixed width for each column and break large columns into multiple lines. Example:

Cell:
`"Lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet,consectetur,adipiscing,elit,sed,do,eiusmod,tempor,incididunt,ut,labore,et,dolore,magna,aliqua.,Ut,enim,ad,minim,veniam,quis,nostrud,exercitation,ullamco,laboris,nisi,ut,aliquip,ex,ea,commodo,consequat"`

Turns into:

```
'Lorem,'
'ipsum,'
'dolor,'
'sit,'
'amet,'
'consectetur,'
'adipiscing,'
'elit,'
'sed,'
'do,'
'eiusmod,'
'tempor,'
'incididunt,'
'ut,'
'labore,'
'et,'
'dolore,'
'magna,'
'aliqua.,'
'Ut,'
'enim,'
'ad,'
'minim,'
'veniam,'
'quis,'
'nostrud,'
'exercitation,'
'ullamco,'
'laboris,'
'nisi,'
'ut,'
'aliquip,'
'ex,'
'ea,'
'commodo,'
'consequat'
```

And all other cells are properly adjusted as well.

I've tried to write it as `',\n'.join([item for item in raw_row[3] if item])` but does not work.

Comment: There are only [5 threads on SO about pytablewriter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pytablewriter) so it's unlikely you'll get the specific answer for this. If you really need a solution my advice would be editing the question to include an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of `matrix` that allows to solve this using only the `pytablewriter` library with the `matrix` (that way you get more potential answers). I'm also adding the question to include the Psycopg tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this without altering your data through custom CSS with the [`nth-child` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) and the `rst-class` directive.

Very roughly, and assuming the fourth column is the trouble.

### file.rst

```
.. rst-class:: my-table

[pytablewriter output]
```

### custom.css

```
table.my-table tbody tr td:nth-child(4) {
    width: 30%;
}
```